# Alternative way of calling Layout API from .Net core App

Tags: jss, jss-rendering-sdk, .net

In `Sitecore 10.2` (Using `.Net Core rendering SDK`), is there any altervative way to call Layout API apart from below example.

```
    public class DefaultController : Controller 
    { 
      [UseSitecoreRendering] 
      public IActionResult Index(Route route) 
      { 
        return View(route); 
      } 
    }
```

I want to call Layout API and populate route object instead of Middleware filter as shown above so that I can modify request param for Layout API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update rendering engine with a query parameter in configure services

```
services.AddSitecoreRenderingEngine(options =>
            {
                //Register your components here
                options
                .MapToRequest(
                      (httpRequest, sitecoreLayoutRequest) => sitecoreLayoutRequest.Language(**httpRequest.Query["lang"]**));
            })
```

Then call API with passing lang in query string
**https://HostingAPI/APIEndpoints?lang=en-au**